# Implementing SSL/TLS with Spring Cloud Gateway, Spring Microservices and Consul

Tags: java, ssl, microservices, consul, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a project that uses Spring Cloud Gateway, Spring Microservices and Consul for Service discovery.  I need guidance on how to implement SSL/TLS with this architecture.

So far everything is setup.  The gateway exposes all the microservices that are registered in consul.  Now I just want to add a secure layer but I am not fully understanding how to setup the following:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/2.1.x/multi/multi__tls_ssl.html

Do I need to add anything to the application.yml files of the microservices, or do I only add what is in the documentation to the Gateway?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If possible, please provide a bit more information on your problem like where you got to, where you are stuck. The way the question is currently put is a little too open, which will make it difficult to answer accurately. If you can narrow the scope of the question, you will see that you get more and better answers. Cheers.

Comment: @Jack Thanks!  Let me know if more than this is needed!

Comment: You should be fine. I generally avoid adding links to more pages which makes it more work for someone else who needs to support you. Generally following the question guidelines is a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Jack I'll keep that in mind for future questions.  Thank you.